# Duvida sobre código jquery

Tags: jquery

Galera é assim quando o usuário clica-se na div vermelha que é a div_2 ela ia sumir e aparecer a div verde que é a div_1, mas esta dando um erro a div vermelha não esta sumindo.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.div_1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #060; }
.div_2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #300; }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".div_1").css("display", "none");
});
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.div_2').click(function(){
$(".div_1").css("display", "block");
$(".div_2").css("display", "nome");
});
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De novo? `nome` != `none`...

Comment: KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK Cara não tinha visto isso.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro de digitação e dificilmente será útil a outras pessoas.

Comment: Mas o erro é diferente de o de antes

Comment: Confira [este outro comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11702/ajuda-com-erros-nos-c#comment20168_11702) que fiz. Acho que também se aplica ao seu caso.

Comment: @brasofilo Mas você esta totalmente errado, eu estou a tempos já procurando uma solução e nada.

Comment: Ok, era só uma impressão... Boa sorte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no código `$(".div_2").css("display", "nome");`, você quis dizer `none`.

Adicionalmente veja que o jQuery possui métodos convenientes para exibir e esconder elementos, respectivamente [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) e [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$(".div_1").show();
$(".div_2").hide();
```

Comment: Vo nem zua de min mesmo, vai que é duença

Comment: Olha to des das 2 da tarde nesse codigo

Comment: Anthony, não sabia desse método obrigadaa =D